# How to use the Vuetify DateFnsAdapter

Tags: vuetify.js, locale

I am tring to use a `v-date-picker` to show the calendar and date in UK format, e.g. *19/10/2023* rather than the US format *10/19/2023* (for today's date).
The [vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#props) have this

```
import DateFnsAdapter from '@date-io/date-fns'
import enUS from 'date-fns/locale/en-US'
import svSE from 'date-fns/locale/sv'

createVuetify({
  date: {
    adapter: DateFnsAdapter,
    locale: {
      en: enUS,
      sv: svSE,
    },
  },
})
```

which I have used, and added

```
import enGB from 'date-fns/locale/en-GB'
```

and added `gb: enGB` to the `locale` option. I also enclosed `v-data-picker` in the template with `<v-locale-provider locale="gb">`

I have installed the correct packages (I hope) with `npm i @date-io/date-fns` and `npm install date-fns`.

But when I run this and open the DataPicker, I get the warning

`Vuetify: Translation key "$vuetify.datePicker.cancel" not found in "gb", trying fallback locale`

The date format now shows correctly but the datepicker returns an incorrect date. I don't need a translation, I just need to convert to GB/EU format instead of US format.

Comment: No help here, so I am now using v-calendar https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar instead, it's a lot better than the veutify labs datepicker